# How to detect and understand an idiomatic expression?

Tags: difference, idioms

I am unable to find the difference between the normal sentences and idiomatic expressions.How to understand the idiomatic expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is an idiom first?

An idiom is *a group of words established by usage as having a meaning **not deducible from those of the individual words.***

Do you see the clue there?

When you see a group of words that *actually* don't make any sense in the context if read as normal words, suspect that it could be an idiom.

Take any idiom in a sentence and you'll find it **odd** i.e. not fitting in the sentence **as normal words**.

> Don't go out; it is *raining cats and dogs* 
>  Don't *beat around the bush*, come to the point 
>  A small group of employees have control over the entire organization ~ Yeah! *Tail wagging the dog*!

If you see all these sentences, the part in *italics* actually does not go with the flow of the sentence if those words are read individually. What do cats and dogs have to do with rains? What has beating the bush to do anything to come to the point? Why a tail would wag the dog; how is it connected with the organization?

But if you study those idioms, you'll find that they not only *perfectly* fit in the sentence but also add great *flair* to the sentences.

Comment: Okay @Maulik how many idioms are there in english to learn becasause I am not able to read a Reading compreshension passage or a newspaper

Comment: How many to learn? As many as you can. There's no *end!* However, you can opt for **top 10/20/50/100** frequently used idioms. Here is [top 50](http://www.smart-words.org/quotes-sayings/idioms-meaning.html) for example.

Comment: @satish "how many idioms are there in english to learn" There is no fixed number because new ones are invented all the time and old ones go out of fashion. Asking how many there are seems like a strange way of trying to learn a language. How would you react if somebody asked you how many verbs there are to learn in your own language?

Comment: @MaulikV - I like your link for the "top 50 English idioms". I'm somewhat glad to see that *raining cats and dogs* isn't on it - it's an idiom that everyone learning English is taught, but is never actually used by native speakers any more!

Comment: @AndyT: except by people in their 70s or 80s.